# RabbitMQ: Consumer connected to an exchange of x-consistent-hash type does not reconnect if the RabbitMQ runs failover

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have an application in NodeJS(node v14.13.1) using amqp-ts library(v1.4.0).
I have some consumers that are consuming from queues and I have consumers consuming from a x-consistent-hash exchange. The problem is, when RabbitMQ goes failover, the consumers that were bind to queues reconnect to the server, but the consumers that were bind to this exchange does not connect.
All of those exchanges are configured as durable.
Do you have any idea if there is either any specific issue related to this type of exchange or any other configuration that is necessary to this type of exchange? I'm reading RabbitMQ doc, but with no luck so far.

I tried changing configurations for that exchange, but not worked so far.
I expect to be able to all of consumers reconnect to the server after a failover.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.